# How to open new jsp page in same tag

Tags: javascript, jsp

I want open new jsp page in same tag. I have home page with frameset including 3 frames.

```
<frameset rows="75%,25%">
    <frameset cols="20%,80%">
        <frame src="TreeGroup.jsp" name="left" />
        <frame src="DispMap.jsp"   name="top" />
    </frameset>
    <frame src="Tabs.jsp" name="bottom"/>
</frameset>
```

in farme 1, I have added TreeGroup.jsp page, in this page I have one javascript fuction. this function  contains

```
function Add_Vehicle(grp_name)
{
  window.open("http://localhost:8080/ITS_Server/vehicleregistration.jsp");
}
```

But it opening in new tag. I don't want want to open new tag, within in a same tag I have to open  vehicleregistration.jsp page...

suppose if I use location.href="path"; it opens new page within same frame not in tag. How to open page in same tag?

Answer (score 0):

Wow frames... haven't seen those in a while

You want to set the target of your link

Sorry, updated:
See http://webcheatsheet.com/html/frame_targetting.php for how to use javascript for this in various scenarios.  Looks like your best bet is:

```
top.frames['framename'].location = 'filename.html';
```

Comment: sir.. I alredy used it. But it open new window not in same tag.